# how to read documents into javascript

Tags: javascript

Please, is it possible to read documents like excel sheets, notepad etc into JavaScript and use the data in the document for computations. Please, if it is possible, I would love to know how to do it. Thank you

Comment: You can use AJAX requests to load files from the same domain/port as your website, and parse them according to their file schemes. There are libraries or APIs for most interesting file formats, for instance the JavaScript API for office is discussed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891051.aspx

Comment: on a web page? for example using an upload button/

Comment: You can use excel sheets as data source files as long as you save them in csv format. Without any problems. If your aim is to build a desktop html application - targeting Explorer, you can make use of FileSystemObject to. Search with: https://www.google.com/#q=msdn+filesystemobject+excel+JScript

Comment: @chika please consider marking the answer if it helped you, otherwise leave a comment if you need further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the selected file without uploading it, but you'll need the HTML5 file API:

```
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
          alert(contents);
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Check this fiddle out:

Just select a txt file https://jsfiddle.net/n454do1d/1/

Comment: It really helped me...thank you...sorry for replying this late